# How do I automatically submit an upload form when a file is selected? how to replace upload button my code is below

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**Code:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                // Upload
                $("#but_upload").click(function(){

                    var fd = new FormData();
                    var files = $('#file')[0].files[0];
                    fd.append('file',files);
                    fd.append('request',1);

                    // AJAX request
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'addremove.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: fd,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function(response){

                            if(response != 0){
                                var count = $('.uploaded-images .image-content').length;
                                count = Number(count) + 1;

                                // Show image preview with Delete button
                                $('.uploaded-images').append("<div class='image-content' id='content_"+count+"' ><img class='image-responsive' src='"+response+"' width='125' height='125'><span class='delete' id='delete_"+count+"'>&times;</span><span class='under-approval'>Under Approval</span></div>");
                            }else{
                                alert('file not uploaded');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

                // Remove file
                $('.uploaded-images').on('click','.image-content .delete',function(){

                    var id = this.id;
                    var split_id = id.split('_');
                    var num = split_id[1];

                     // Get image source
                    var imgElement_src = $( '#content_'+num+' img' ).attr("src");

                    // AJAX request
                    $.ajax({
                       url: 'addremove.php',
                       type: 'post',
                       data: {path: imgElement_src,request: 2},
                       success: function(response){

                            // Remove <div >
                            if(response == 1){
                                $('#content_'+num).remove();
                            }

                       }
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
```

**This is my Questions:**

1. How do I automatically submit an upload form when a file is selected?
2. how to replace upload button my code is below

Anyone who have experience in this field, please suggestion me any solution for this problem, thank you.

Comment: please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before asking question

Comment: And please ask questions a little bit beautifully

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following `JQuery` code:

```
$("#fileInput").change(function () {
    $('#form').submit();
});
```

Comment: how to use?<script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                // Upload
                $("#fileInput").change(function () {
                   $('#form').submit();
                    var fd = new FormData();
                    var files = $('#file')[0].files[0];
                    fd.append('file',files);
                    fd.append('request',1);

Comment: @user9515436 you don't need submit() if you're put your ajax code in change event.

Comment: its working but i have got another problem when uploading the images placing some where and delete/cancel button not working and more –

Comment: its working fine now

Comment: hi in this script width=125 height 125 css using it giving stretched thumbnail how to get rid of it!

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
$('#file').on('change', function() {
    $("#but_upload").click();
});
```

or better just put your click code into change event.

```
$('#file').on('change', function() {
   var fd = new FormData();
   var files = this.files[0];
   ...
});
```

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                // Upload
                $('#file').on('change', function() {
                 $("#but_upload").click();

Comment: its not working i'm not well in javascript

Comment: @user9515436 it's hard to see from your code in comment because it's in one line so it's in comment but you're missing two `});` and the end

Comment: @user9515436 did you include your `$("#but_upload").click(function(){ .... });` ?

Comment: its working now